# Chrome canvas.toDataURL webp red to blue color

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, colors, webp, todataurl

I tried to get a webp image from canvas using "toDataURL" (Quality 1.0). But the problem is that the image is getting blue on many parts.

I cant find anything on web about this problem.

It seems every red type of color is transformed into blue.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? Comment back when you have.